What is the oscillator in this 433MHz transmitter?
I took this image from ev1527 datasheet.
The RF transistor drives the tank circuit to generate rf signal.
What is the name of this rf oscillator?
Is it a Colpits oscillator?
Also there is a project in github about the ev1527 chip


The LX1527 User's guide shows a somewhat different oscillator circuit that adds a surface-acoustic-wave (SAW) resonator to transistor base. It is a type of Colpitts oscillator.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
